# Узнать прочитана ли новость или нет

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос : на различных сайте присутствует функция прочитать новость, после выполнения которой данная новость уже не будет выводиться. Вопрос заключается в следующем: Нужно ли создавать отдельную таблицу в бд? Если да, то получаеться, что нужно при создании каждой новости создавать дополнительно запись в таблице с айди новостью и пользователем и создавать не одну запись ,а столько сколько у нас пользователей зарегистрироваванно?

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь всё понятно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может, достаточно в куках у пользователя запоминать через запятую id прочитанных новостей? Помнить инфу про N последних прочитанных. Допустим, на сайте могут выводиться 20 последних новостей. Тогда пользователю в куках достаточно помнить 20 последних им прочитанных. Более старые - удалять, чтобы не раздувать куку.

**Upd.** Не дописал, что скрывать новости нужно на стороне клиента с помощью JS. Cервер раздаёт всем идетничные страницы. Бразуер клиента отвечает за то, что делать с куками, и что скрывать.

Comment: вариант с куками хорош, но что делать, если пользователь сначала дома почитал, а потом на работе? заново куку прочитанными новостями набивать? можно просто ваш вариант переделать, все тоже самое, только хранение в БД

Comment: Можно. Вариант с куками из философии «слейте максимум нагрузки на клиент, чтобы не грузить сервер». Разумеется, он не универсален.

Не дописал, что скрывать новости нужно на стороне клиента с помощью JS. Т.е. сервер раздаёт всем идетничные страницы. Бразуер клиента отвечает за то, что делать с куками, и что скрывать.

Comment: дак опять же все загнется при смене клиента.. но и каждый раз тягать из базы на проверку читал или нет, при выводе списка в цикле, тоже не особо.. тем не менее, одним клиентом тут не отделаться

Answer (score 5):

Правильнее подойти к проблеме с обратной стороны. При создании новости ничего в дополнительную таблицу не добавлять. Но зато добавлять одну запись в момент прочтения новости конкретным пользователем. Сам факт наличия записи в этой таблице как раз и будет означать то, что этот пользователь данную новость уже прочитал. При отображении новостей нужно будет просто пропускать те новости, для которых уже есть запись о прочтении этим пользователем.